# Dataworks Forge can't establish connection for sql db service

Tags: ibm-cloud, dataconnect

I tried to establish connection using Dataworks Forge for sql db, I got following error.

`Unable to establish a connection using the supplied values.Check that all values are correct and try again. Internal Details: Failed to send the request to the handler: The agent at yp-iis-dataworks-ga-wdc01-2-12-0-0-5-vm5:31531 is not available.; nested exception is: com.ibm.iis.prs.exception.CommunicationException: Failed to send the request to the handler: The agent at yp-iis-dataworks-ga-wdc01-2-12-0-0-5-vm5:31531 is not available.`

I input the values based on VCAP_Service, and double checked it. How can I troubleshoot this?

Connection name sqldb1
Host 75.126.155.1xx
Database SQLDB
User user06xxx
Port 50000
Password xxx

Comment: `The agent at yp-iis-dataworks-ga-wdc01-2-12-0-0-5-vm5:31531` means datawork can't get to a server called yp-iis-dataworks-ga-wdc01-2-12-0-0-5-vm5 on port 31531

Comment: I work in the DevOps CDS team for DataWorks. There is no current issue with the above DataWorks server (yp-iis-dataworks-ga-wdc01-2-12-0-0-5-vm5) and the listener is active with no reported errors in the past 10 days or so. If you can provide me the details of when you experienced this issue, then I can look at the DataWorks Forge UI logs for that day and time to see why there was this issue. Thanks, Nigel Terry

Comment: Thank you Nick, Nigel. Now I can establish connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I did same thing when I posted this question and could establish connection successfully.

As Nigel mentioned, the dataworks service states when I posted was green. But maybe there were some issues. And they were fixed now.